# Error al intentar almacenar en una base de datos id de variable de sesión

Tags: php, mysqli, session

Saludos tengo un usuario que se loguea, luego de que inicia sesión almaceno todos los datos de la sesión en un array:

```
   <?php 
    session_start();
    include "./conexion.php";
    if(isset($_POST['correo']) && isset($_POST['clave']) ){
    
    $resultado = $conexion->query("select * from usuario where 
    correo='".$_POST['correo']."' and 
    clave='".sha1($_POST['clave'])."'")or die($conexion->error);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado)>0){
        $datos_usuario = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado);
        $nombre = $datos_usuario[1];
        $id_usuario = $datos_usuario[0];
        $correo = $datos_usuario[3];
        $id_nivel_usuario= $datos_usuario[7];
        $_SESSION['datos_logueo']= array(
            'nombre'=>$nombre,
            'id_usuario'=>$id_usuario,
            'correo'=>$correo,
            'id_nivel_usuario'=>$id_nivel_usuario
    
        ); 
        header("Location: ../admin/");
    
    }else{
        header("location: ../login.php?error=Datos incorrectos");
    }
    
    }else{
    
    }
?>
```

Una vez inicia sesión entra en su administrador y su tarea es rigistrar una publicación mediante un formulario para almacenarla en la base de datos especificamente en la tabla "publicacion" la cual está relacionada con la tabla "usuario", por lo que al registrar la publicacion debe guardarse en la tabla "publicacion" el id_usuario que está logueado haciendo el registro.

Este es el archivo donde hago la consulta para guardar los datos

```
  <?php 
    session_start();
    include "./conexion.php";
    if(!isset($_SESSION['datos_logueo'])){header("location: ./index.php");}
    
    
    if(isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['caracteristicas']) && isset($_POST['descripcion']) 
    && isset($_POST['precio']) &&  isset($_POST['inventario']) && isset($_POST['ubicacion']) 
    && isset($_POST['telefono1']) && isset($_POST['telefono2']) && isset($_POST['categoria'])
    && isset($_POST['subcategoria']) && isset($_POST['estado'])){
    
        $carpeta="../imagenes/"; 
        $nombre= $_FILES['imagen1']['name'];
        
        //imagen.algo.jpg
        $temp= explode( '.' ,$nombre);
        $extension= end($temp);
    
        $nombrefinal = time().'.'.$extension;
    
        if($extension=='jpg'|| $extension=='png'){
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen1']['tmp_name'], $carpeta.$nombrefinal)){
                $fecha= date('Y-m-d h:m:s');
                $fecha_fin = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fecha. "+ 31 day"));
                //$fecha_fin = ADDATE($fecha, INTERVAL 31 DAY);
                $id_usuario = $conexion -> insert_id;
                $conexion->query("insert into publicacion
                (nombre,caracteristicas,descripcion,precio,inventario,ubicacion,telefono1,
                telefono2,imagen1,fecha_inicio,fecha_fin,id_usuario,id_estado,id_estatus_publicacion,
                id_categoria,id_subcategoria) values
                (
                '".$_POST['nombre']."',
                '".$_POST['caracteristicas']."',
                '".$_POST['descripcion']."',
                ".$_POST['precio'].",
                ".$_POST['inventario'].",
                '".$_POST['ubicacion']."',
                ".$_POST['telefono1'].",
                ".$_POST['telefono2'].",
                '$nombrefinal',     
                '$fecha',
                '$fecha_fin',
                $id_usuario,
                ".$_POST['estado'].",
                '1',
                ".$_POST['categoria'].",
                ".$_POST['subcategoria']."
              )
                ")or die ($conexion->error);
                header("Location: ../admin/publicacion.php?success"); 
    
            }else{
            header("Location: ../admin/publicacion.php?error=No se pudo subir la imagen"); 
            }
        }else{
            header("Location: ../admin/publicacion.php?error=Por favor subir imagen jpg o png");  
        }
    }else{
    header("Location: ../admin/publicacion.php?error=Llene todos los campos");
    }
    ?>
```

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`lacorotera`.`publicacion`, CONSTRAINT `publicacion_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`id_usuario`) REFERENCES `usuario` (`id_usuario`))

ESTE ES EL ERROR QUE ME GENERA, GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO A QUIENES PUEDAN AYUDARME.

Comment: Esto `$id_usuario = $conexion -> insert_id;`, creo que deberías tomarlo de la sesión.

Comment: Gracias por responder, ya lo había solucionado, asigne a una variable todo el arreglo de la sesión y luego a otra variable le asigne el arreglo en el campo que quería                                                                      $arreglousuario = $_SESSION['datos_logueo'];
$id = $arreglousuario['id_usuario'];

Answer (score 0):

Solución:
Asigne el arreglo completo de la variable de sesión a la variable $arreglousuario
y luego a otra variable le asigne la variable $arreglousuario en el campo que quería del arreglo.

$arreglousuario = $_SESSION['datos_logueo'];
$id = $arreglousuario['id_usuario'];

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta